# Glob pattern for everything including hidden files

Tags: javascript, linux, glob

I try to get a glob pattern which includes every file in every subdirectory, but I can't figure out how to include hidden files.

Example, all those should match:

```
.git
.github/workflow.yml
index.js
src/index.js
src/components/index.js
```

This works for all files with name and extension, but leaves out hidden files:

```
**/**
```

More specific background: I want so make an archive with all files except `node_modules` (and potentially some others), using the [archiver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/archiver) library.

```js
archive.directory("???", {
    ignore: ["node_modules/", ...some other files],
});
```

Comment: You could use {.,}** to include hidden files with all files or type unset GLOBIGNORE just before your statement to include hidden files

Comment: But with `{.,}**` `.github/workflow.yml` won't match. I need to include everything.

Comment: This is brace expansion it simply puts .* and * respectively since the first one starts with dot(.) it should include hidden files since they also start with dot. Didn’t try the command that i sent you but just play around i should work

Answer (score 0):

The best way is probably to use two separate patterns, one of which matches the hidden files, and one which matches the non-hidden files.
One way to do this is `.* *`. However, this matches the directory itself `.` and parent `..` as well, which is usually not what you want.

A pattern which avoids this problem is `.??* *`. Suppose you have the following files in your directory.

```
file1  file2  .hidden
```

As you can see in the example below, this glob pattern matches both hidden files and non-hidden files, but not the current directory or its parent.

```
$ ls -l .??* *
-rw-r--r-- 1 amy users 0 Jul 30 18:00 file1
-rw-r--r-- 1 amy users 0 Jul 30 18:00 file2
-rw-r--r-- 1 amy users 0 Jul 30 18:00 .hidden
```

Comment: This is a neat solution but it won't always work. First, `.??*` won't match a filename such as `.a`. Second, because there are two separate globs, the shell will fail if either of them don't match. For example, if the directory has no hidden files, or if the directory only has hidden files. Otherwise, thanks for the useful idea.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem when using the archiver library. I read in the docs that it is using for the glob pattern the [minmatch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/minimatch) library. The library offering an option for the specific issue. [Here is the location in the docs](https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch#dot). To get all files, directories (recursive) and hidden files like ".npmrc" you need to use "archive.glob instead of "archive.directory".

My code looks like this:

```
archive.glob('**/*', {
  cwd: __dirname,
  dot: true,
  ignore: ['node_modules/**', '<name of your zipfile>.zip']
});
```

I've passed the option "dot: true" and now it includes hidden files as well.

The final code would look like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const archiver = require('archiver');

const zipname = "the name of your zipfile"

const output = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + `/${zipname}.zip`);
const archive = archiver('zip', { zlib: { level: 9 } });

output.on('close', function () {
  console.log(archive.pointer() + ' total bytes');
  console.log('archiver has been finalized and the output file descriptor has closed.');
});

archive.on('error', function (err) {
  throw err;
});

archive.pipe(output);

archive.glob('**/*', {
  cwd: __dirname,
  dot: true,
  ignore: ['node_modules/**', `${zipname}.zip`]
}
);

archive.finalize();
```